# How can I convert a CSS stylesheet to inlined CSS styles?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

When it comes to sending HTML-formatted emails and/or making purists' heads explode, nothing beats tons of inline styles.  I've found some tools to do this on a case-by-case basis, but I'd like to be able to do it programatically as part of my node.js application's normal processing.

So, how can I accomplish this using server-side JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a Node.js module called [Styliner](https://github.com/SLaks/Styliner) that does exactly this.

Comment: cool, nice project! I'll give it a try.

Comment: "not a real question", yet it got a real answer!  Those who closed it have obviously never had to apply CSS to an HTML email.